# WordPress Date Not Showing When Using the_date()

Tags: wordpress

The problem I am encountering is that the date is only showing up on certain posts. I'm currently using the `the_date` function to display the date.

How do I fix this to apply the date to all posts?

Comment: It's preferable to post code samples and a complete description of the problem you're having instead of a link to your site.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. It wasn't an attempt to drive traffic or anything, I don't even have AdSense going. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: No worries, it's more of a general rule - hard to tell what something will be before you click it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My guess is that you're using `the_date()`. As stated in the WordPress documentation if there are multiple posts from the same day, it will only show once.

> *When there are multiple posts on a page published under
> the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post
> (that is, the first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for
> posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag
> the_time() or get_the_date() (since 3.0) with a date-specific format
> string. Use  to add the
> date set in the admin interface.*

Use `the_time` or `get_the_date()` instead. Note that `the_time` echoes while `get_the_time` won't.

Both functions takes an optional parameter which gives you the chance to specify the date format you'd like returned. That parameter follows the PHP Date Format and you can read more about that at php.net: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Hey unfortunately my reputation is not high enough to upvote this yet or I would. Thanks so much for this help. This is great!

Comment: Unfortunately, the date is still not showing when using `<?php get_the_date($d); ?>`

Comment: And what is $d in this case? Try removing it, that way WordPress will use your default date format. Also get_the_date won't echo anything as I previously wrote.

Comment: When I remove it, no date shows whatsoever for any posts on the front page. This happened after installing my WordPress theme only. This is why I'm trying to add it back.

Comment: <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again for the help! I really appreciate it. I can give you a tiny gift on PayPal if you want :) (if that's against the rules here, ignore I said that). I'm a real novice. What exactly does 'echo' do for future reference?

Comment: No, answers are free ;) Echo will create output. In this case you'll be able to see what was "echoed" mixed in with the HTML.

Comment: Oh, okay. I get that. It's working now. I really love StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

It only shows up once because that's how a diary would work. It would show the date at the top and you would write your entries below it. Use echo get_the_date instead this will echo it out for each post instead once for all the dates that day.

```
<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
```

For more info you can read about it here: [WordPress Date Not Showing When Using the_date()](https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/the_date-function-wordpress-shows-once-first-post/)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this, is simple as all the previous mentioned here

```
the_time('d/m/y');
```

My 50 cent to this question is the `is_new_day()` function which basically checks if the `global $currentday, $previousday;` are the same.

so with a simple if/else statement like this:

```
if ( !is_new_day() ) {
  echo '<span>-//-</span>';
} else {
  the_date('d/m/y');
}
```

So depending from your design (eg. in a list the duplication is not nice, in cards it is mandatory) you can keep this little nice touch with the avoidance of duplicated dates adding a symbol.

neat eh?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y') ; ?>
```